# Change tkinter window border style

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to make the frame of my window look like the old windows 95 style.
Right now when i create a window tkinter automatically adopts the style of my os (windows 10).
Is there a way to change this?

Comment: I dont think there is a tkinter so called "layout".Its the basic layout the GUI is created in for all OS.

Comment: [tkinter.ttk — Tk themed widgets](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.ttk.html). But I don't know if it works with window border. In some systems border is created by system, not by tkinter.

Comment: So the only way to do this would be to hide the border and recreate it using buttons etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing specifically available to make the window border look different. Your only choice is to remove the border completely (eg: `root.overrideredirect(True)`) and draw the border yourself using a canvas and/or images.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll do that then